# Call forwarding loop instead of redirect

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, subdomain

I have a code in django view (django==2.1), where I want to redirect from sub domain to main domain.

```
def signup(request):
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
    if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] != current_site.domain:
        full = urljoin(current_site.domain, reverse('accounts:signup'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(full)
```

Instead of redirecting, there's a redirecting loop. And instead of the full address, there is the ending: `/accounts/signup/`. 
It should be `http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/`

Comment: What are the actual values of `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` and `current_site.domain`?

Comment: request.META['HTTP_HOST'] - ```test2.localhost:8000``` and current_site.domain - ```localhost:8000```

Comment: For sudomains I thing it would be better if you check [django-subdomains](https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/) or django hosts